# ScrollView jumps to top after setContentSize

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, hidden

I have a ScrollView with some Views. I set some elements hidden on button click. My problem is that the ScrollView jumps to top (0,0) on reset the contentsize of the scrollview. I set the ScrollView content size as follows:

```
if(![subview isHidden]){
      scrollViewHeight += subViewFrame.size.height;
}

[scrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(320, scrollViewHeight + 20))];
```

Comment: check the value in the scrollViewHeight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes ,whenever you are changing the content size then automatically `contentOffset` value taken as `(0,0)`.after changing the frame we can set `contentOffset` value related to newly generated scrollview frame.

Comment: yes once again you can set contentOffset value after changing the frame.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With `[scrollView setContentOffset:contOffset animated:FALSE];, saving the contOffset on click and a little catch for the special cases it works great.